# ANDROID. why FAIL, PUBLIC_STATIC_STRING_IDENTIFIER, STATIC_INTEGER_VALUE, etc

Tags: android, static, integer

I'm new and I have this problem

```
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {     
  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data); 
  switch(requestCode) { 
    case (STATIC_INTEGER_VALUE) : {                                         
      if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) { 
      int tabIndex = data.getIntExtra(PUBLIC_STATIC_STRING_IDENTIFIER);
      // TODO Switch tabs using the index.
      } 
      break; 
    } 
  } 
}
```

PUBLIC_STATIC_STRING_IDENTIFIER and STATIC_INTEGER_VALUE say me

"PUBLIC_STATIC_STRING_IDENTIFIER cannot be resolved to a variable"
and
"STATIC_INTEGER_VALUE cannot be resolved to a variable"

I need to import java... shomething?

Comment: You need to define the values.

Comment: Actually what are you trying to do???Those are variables...Have you defined values for that?

Comment: STATIC_INTEGER_VALUE  is a requestcode so it must be defined as a requestcode (private static int STATIC_INTEGER_VALUE =100 ) and PUBLIC_STATIC_STRING_IDENTIFIER is a String you have passed into Intent.

Answer (score 0):

There are some mistakes You have possibly not thought about. You need to initialize these variables like this (do it in a global way):

```
 public static PUBLIC_STATIC_STRING_IDENTIFIER = 0;
 public static STATIC_INTEGER_VALUE = 1;
```

. And then

```
   @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
      if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        switch(requestCode) {

           case (STATIC_INTEGER_VALUE) :
           int tabIndex = data.getIntExtra(PUBLIC_STATIC_STRING_IDENTIFIER);

           break;

           case(PUBLIC_STATIC_STRING_IDENTIFIER):

           //do some stuff that You want to do....

           break;
        }
      }
    }
```

Think about that the variables have to be integers. I think we could give You further help, if You explain exactly what You want to do....

Comment: Wow! then... I can change PUBLIC_STATIC_STRING_IDENTIFIER myIntPreferName;